# limit the results of a query server side

Tags: voltrb

I would like to know how to limit a query (server side. My knowledge is Meteor). For example, the comments of a particular post instead of retrieving all the comments in database.

I want it to be limited server side to avoid malicious client to fetch all the data of the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we talked about this in gitter, but I'm planning to add a query_restrictions api where you can reject queries that you don't like.  I'll probably add a default globally configurable limit also.  (that you can override on a per model basis)

Answer (score 0):

You could use limit. For example: 
    post.comments.limit(10)

Comment: yes, but then a malicious client could do a `post.comments.limit(100000)`, for example.